# How to split data using space MS Excel

Tags: excel

Data Block

119 122 140 141 155 163 170 179 203 226 232 233 238 243 244 245 247 248 253 254 255 256 257 261 262 263 264 265 266 270 272 273 275 278 279 281 287 288 289 801 802 808 863 865 1103 1115 1117 1118 1120 1747 1770 1772 1773 1854 1855 6301 6304 6305 6311 6319 6321 6323 6324 6327 6328 6331 6332 6334 6335 6340 6346 6349 6350 6351 6357 6361 6363 6364 6365 6367 6368 6369 6371 6374 6375 6377 6380 6851 6853 6864 6865 6869 6890 6921 6932 6935 6936 6951 6959 6974 8446 8447 8472 8528 8531 8926 8929 8954

Output separated rows

```
119
------
122
------ 
140 
------
141
-------
155
------
163
```

---

Comment: Is the data block one long line, or many lines?

Comment: One long line I want to split into rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firs select cell and use data -> text to columns, and split data as columns, than copy the columns and paste special and select transpose check.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]